# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker does not automatically return new access token from refresh token

Tags: .net, google-api, google-oauth, gdata, google-api-dotnet-client

I use the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker class form .Net Client library which stores an access token and a refresh token in the file storage, like this :

```
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret },
                                 scopes, "XXXXXX", CancellationToken.None
            ,new FileDataStore("XXXXXX")
                                ).Result;
```

If works, but after one hour, when the acces token is invalid, when launching the AuthorizeAsync again, the access tokens returned in the "credential" object is not renewed, as it should be (I cheked the values in the debug mode and the acces token is still the same, not renewed). Even the browser does not launch to ask user for granting permission (i use it for the Google contacts API).

I use OAuth2 with .Net google client library to authentificate, since is much simplier than then authentification with the gdata library.
Nevertheless I use the old gdata lib to update gmail contacts (the new contact API does not allow YET contact data modification).

Is there a problem with mixing those APIs ? Should i autentificate with the gdata library ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope it is arguably the easiest way to authenticate to a gdata api is to use the discovery library for authentication.

You haven't shown how you are applying the access token to your gdata request but I am going to assume that's working fine.

The thing is that the discovery library the one containing "GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker" uses FileDatastore to refresh your access token.  It does it when it needs it.  You aren't making any requests using it so it never bothers to refresh your access token.   The easiest way of doing this is to make a dummy request using a discovery api.  I normally just use the people api.

[People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) sending a parameter of 'me' just gets some dummy info on the currently authenticated user.   If the access token has expired then it will fetch you a new one.

I am going to dig around in the library a little I am wonder why we don't have a force refresh access token method for times like this.

**Update:**

you will need to add the scope `PlusService.Scope.PlusMe` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`.

```
var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Google Plus Authentication Sample",
            });

// dummy call to api to refresh the auth token if needed.
var refresh = service.People.Get("me").Execute();
```

**Update2:**

After a bit of digging around in the client library I found that there is a method for forcing an update of the access token

```
var m = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
```

Unfortunately its going to be an hour before I can verify that it works.  The background code checks if the current access token has expired or not before trying to refresh it so I need to wait for one to expire.

Comment: Thanx DaImto. I used the code in your blog http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/ for using the gdata requests. In fact you mentioned in this blog in the comments section that you cheked in debug mode and see that after an hour the acces token returned by AuthorizeAsync is renewed. I used the same code and it does not. Why ? As for the People.get workaround, could you point out some sample c# code ?

Comment: you might want to try playing with the people api.  https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections it appears to read from google contacts.

Comment: how do i create the "service" object ?

Comment: Thank you, DaImTo, it worked like a charm ;) with the service.People.Get. I also had to activate the Google + API of course on the google console API (I mention that for other pople to know when they read the solution).

Comment: So it worked for me with the Update 1. Can you report if it worked for you  with Update 2 solution ? Thanx.

Comment: It also worked for me with the single line in Update 1 (so without the update 2). Update 2 is a cleaner solution than update 1.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my last comment, i meant to say it also worked with the single line in the Update 2 (without Update 1)

Comment: Access token will update when it needs to by it self.   The first one will be requested when you make the first request to the API.   But yes GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync works if you want to force it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Getting the Access Token for a REST call wasn't forcing the refresh.  Adding `string temp = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;` to the call fixed it.  Finally.

Comment: even if I call var m = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(); this end check my credentials.Token.accessToken it still is same, am I missing something?

Comment: If it hasnt expired it will be the same.